# search filter in js

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs

I've created a search filter that looks like this:

```
const booksrow = books && books.map(book=>{
 if(pattern.test('all')||pattern.test(book.genre.toLowerCase())||pattern.test(book.title.toLowerCase())||pattern.test(book.author.toLowerCase())){
  return <Book  book={book} books={books}/>
}
})
```

Where I'm mapping through an array and just filtering it based off of certain requirements, the problem that I'm having is that i would like to return a default message if nothing is returned from this filter.
For example, i tried doing

```
 const booksrow = books && books.map(book=>{
if(pattern.test('all')||pattern.test(book.genre.toLowerCase())||pattern.test(book.title.toLowerCase())||pattern.test(book.author.toLowerCase())){
  return <Book  book={book} books={books}/>
}else {
 return 'Default message'
 }
})
```

But this doesnt work because it will return this default message based off of the map.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `filter` instead of `map`, then you can check to see if the filtered array is empty or not:

```
const filtered = books
    ?.filter(book => (
        pattern.test('all') ||
        ['genre', 'title', 'author'].some(prop => pattern.test(book[prop].toLowerCase()))
    ))
    .map(book => <Book book={book} books={books} />);
const booksRow = filtered?.length ? filtered : 'Default message';
```